# How to escape double quotes for a SQLite insert statement - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sqlite

I have the following insert statement in my Angular application to insert into the local SQLite DB.

```
INSERT INTO testtable (ID, userID, goTime, backTime, imageFileNames) VALUES (8,1,"00:00:00","00:00:00","{\"images\":[\"U9P0v8302e5fnrHd3D0lk04CDDONdYEF1p1cDDICLpQMZDTZXgcCigeNEZZHdA0rvcfhrIouMixH6XUKOOCe64Hcrmkf5QZuc9YY.jpg\"]}");
```

I am having a syntax error thrown around the images section of the insert statement. I know this is because of the double quotes within and that added a extra " to the internal double quotes will work.

My questions is: is there a function or a way to easily add those extra double quotes where needed so that the statement becomes valid again?

Comment: What are the actual values that you want to insert?

Comment: Why? [SQL Error code sqlite3\_prepare\_v2 failure: syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473494/sql-error-code-sqlite3-prepare-v2-failure-syntax-error)

Comment: @forpas when inserted it will look something like: 

{"images":["U9P0v8302e5fnrHd3D0lk04CDDONdYEF1p1cDDICLpQMZDTZXgcCigeNEZZHdA0rvcfhrIouMixH6XUKOOCe64Hcrmkf5QZuc9YY.png"]}

in the column imageFileNames ie saved as a string

Comment: You don't need to escape anything. Enclose the text value inside single quotes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3cc7ed7f3298ef6f173d69a147d25162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could mix **backtips** (`) with **single quotes** (') and **double  quotes** ("):

```
INSERT INTO testtable (ID, userID, goTime, backTime, imageFileNames) 
VALUES (
   8,
   1,
   "00:00:00",
   "00:00:00",
   `{"images:['U9P0v8302e5fnrHd3D0lk04CDDONdYEF1p1cDDICLpQMZDTZXgcCigeNEZZHdA0rvcfhrIouMixH6XUKOOCe64Hcrmkf5QZuc9YY.jpg']}"`
);
```

if it doesn't work, try this way:

```
  "{`images:['U9P0v8302e5fnrHd3D0lk04CDDONdYEF1p1cDDICLpQMZDTZXgcCigeNEZZHdA0rvcfhrIouMixH6XUKOOCe64Hcrmkf5QZuc9YY.jpg']}`"
```